# Stop single/all processes of a website on shared hosting

Tags: c#, asp.net, rackspace, kill-process

I have an ASP.NET website hosted on Rackspace Cloud Sites.

I have some C# code running which loops through a text file and inserts the records to a SQL Server website. Currently I have this code running and the records are being uploaded, but I would like to stop the upload.

I tried removing the web.config from the website (as suggested by a Rackspace rep) but I still see the records being uploaded in the database.

Is there a way for me to stop the code from running?

Thanks.

Comment: Ask them to recycle your AppPool.

Comment: @vcsjones They said that would stop if for the time it's recycling, but the processes would resume afterward.

Comment: @vcsjones I guess that rep was wrong - called again and asked to recycle it and it worked. Thanks. (Add your comment as answer so I can mark it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ask them to Recycle your AppPool, that should stop the processing.